# Redshift - is it possible to run query that select from external table - only if table exist

Tags: redshift

what i am try to do is something like this:

```
select 
case when (/* here should come sql statement that check if table exist */)
then 
 (select count(*) from my_external_table)
else 
  0 
end
```

I know that theoretically i could use the SVV_ALL views , but it's sometimes it's cuasing the query to be slow ..

As an example for what i am looking for , this postgres query could be great for me , but Redshift do not support the `to_regclass` function:

```
select 
case when exist(select * from (select to_regclass('my_table') as rg) where rg IS NOT NULL )
then 
 (select count(*) from my_table)
else 
  0 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to use a [stored procedure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-overview.html), I suggest splitting the logic into two queries.

With the first query checking the logic:

```sql
SELECT CASE
WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.svv_tables WHERE table_schema = 'yourschema' AND table_name = 'yourtable')
THEN TRUE
ELSE FALSE
END
```

And then executing your other query based on this result. In my case, I'm running the query in a [Lambda function](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) so it was easy to move the logic there.